# Schengen visa transit in other Schengen country

Tags: airport-transfer, us-residents, dominican-citizens

I possess a Dominican passport with a legal resident US card. Planing to travel to Milan with a possible stop in a other Schengen country! If traveling from the USA into Germany Frankfort or any other Schengen area before arriving at my intended final destination do I need a special visa to enter any of the other countries I mention?

PS: I already have a visa to enter Italy.

Comment: What type of Italian visa do you have?

Answer (score 1):

Dominican citizens do need a visa to enter the Schengen area but just about any Italian visa should be good for that. You will enter the Schengen area and get your passport stamped during your layover in Frankfurt. For this reason, it's important that the validity of your Italian starts before the date you will land in German (and not merely when you would enter Italy) and covers the whole stay including any layover on the way in or out of Italy.

Comment: As a small addition, it should be stated that the Italian visa must both cover the time of presence in Germany and the stay in Italy (in terms of the validity period and the overall number of days that the visa holder may be present in the Schengen area during the validity period).

Answer (score 0):

Italy is in in Schengen zone so if you get visa for Schengen zone you will be covered for both Italy and Germany. If you're a US citizen you can be in schengen for 90 days without any visa. But not sure how it works if you're a US resident- you may need to do some research.